# return array with some items only if they exist in another array

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have a function that has an initial array with some top products and should return an array with the items that exist on the $topProds array.

```
$topProds = ['laptop', 'printer', 'keyboard', 'monitor', 'usb adaptor'];
```

The function receives some information that comes from an API (`array $prod`) and should return an array with this format:

```
prods: [
    
    {
        label: 'Laptop',
    },
    {
        label: 'Printer',
    },
    {
        label: 'Usb Adaptor',
    }
],
```

Only the products that exist on the topProds array should be returned. For example there there might be cases where there there is a 'paper' product but since its not in the $topProds array should not be returned on the function.

I'm trying to achieve that with the function below, but like this it doesn't work. Im not understanding how to besides the map, how to return only the items that exist on the $topProds array.

```
public function getTopProducts(array $prod): array
    {
        $topProds = ['laptop', 'printer', 'keyboard', 'monitor', 'usb adaptor'];
    
        collect($prod['content']['data'])->map(function ($prod) {
            return [
                'label' => $prod['title'],
            ];
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `reject()` method of Laravel Collections? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-reject. You'd be able to "reject" each object in `$prod` if its label doesn't match any of the records in `$topProds`

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew that method. But after use that reject method still need to use the map method to have the return as it is on the question right?

Comment: If you did `$rejected = collect($prod)->reject(...)`, then `$rejected` would be a copy of `$prod` with any objects filtered out if they aren't in `$topProd`; so I don't think you'd need to do the `->map()` call, since I'm not exactly sure what it's doing... If you needed the data in a specific format, then `->reject()->map()` is valid too

Comment: are you sure that formula mentioned correct , 
i see differences between `prods` structure and how you deal with it in `getTopProducts` 
also the index is `label` or `title` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with filter:

```
$topProds = collect(['laptop', 'printer', 'keyboard', 'monitor', 'usb adaptor']);
$prods = collect(['laptop', 'printer', 'monitor', 'usb']);

 
$res = $prods->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($topProds) {
    return $topProds->contains($value); //return only if $topProds contains the current $value in the $prods collection
})->map(function($val){
  return [ 'label' => ucwords($val)];
});
 
$res->all(); //outputs similar to your result but array of arrays. You can use json_encode([ 'label' => $val]) if you want json objects
```

Comment: Thanks. But for example to get the $prods collection as you have with an array with values operated by , how do you properly achieve that? $prod = collect($prod['content']['data'])->map(function ($prod) {
            return
                $prod['title'];
        }). I get ^ Illuminate\Support\Collection {#423 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => "Laptop"
    1 => "Paper"

  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}. So Im getting a collection of items not just values separated by ,.

Comment: The collections I have shared are exactly the same as this though; If you dd those, the result will be similar.